# Email Alignment Issue

Tags: html, html-email

Use Case:
Using an HTML email template. Aligns properly in one version, but latest version the alignment of the contents are off

Current:

[image]

Working Example:

[image]

Seems only be isolated to Outlook 2010 from Litmus tests.

Markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Financial conversations you should have with your spouse</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 94%;">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<style type="text/css">
body, td, th {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #666666;}body {background-color: #FFFFFF;}a, a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {color:#005596;}@media only screen and (device-width : 720px) and (orientation : portrait),only screen and (min-device-width : 319px) and (max-device-width : 540px),only screen and (device-width : 800px),only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3) and (max-device-width: 718px),only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){ table, table td {width: auto !important;}td[class=mobile_hide] {width: 0 !important;display: none !important;}td[class=mobile_hide] img {display: none !important;}td[class=header-img], td[class=header-img] img {width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;}td[class=img-right] {padding: 5% 7% 5% 5% !important;}td[class=img-right] img{width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;}td[class=left-column] {width: 
100% !important;}td[class=right1] {display: inline-block !important;width: 25% !important;height: auto !important;padding: 3% 2% 3% 3% !important;}td[class=right1] img{display: inline-block !important; width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;max-height: none !important;}td[class=right2] {display: inline-block !important;width: 60% !important;height: auto !important;padding: 3% 3% 3% 0 !important;font-size: 11px !important;max-height:none !important;}td[class=right2] img {display: inline-block !important;width: 60% !important;height: auto !important;padding: 3% 3% 3% 0 !important;max-height: none !important;}td[class=right3] {display: inline-block !important;width: 100% !important;height: 50% !important;}td[class=right3] img{display: inline-block !important;width: 100% !important;height: 65% !important;}td[class=padding3] {padding: 3% 3% 0 3% !important;}td[class=padding4] 
{padding: 3% 3% 3% 3% !important;}td[class=padding5] {padding: 0 3% 3% 3% !important;}td[class=space] {width: 100% !imporant;height: 3% !important;background-color: #ecf1f4 !important;}td[class=header-logo]{width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;display: block !important;}td[class=header-logo] img[class=mobile-logo1] {width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;display: block !important;}td[class=mobile_hide] img{display: none !important;}td[class=mobile_hide] td{display: none !important;}table[class=mobile-show]{display: block !important;max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;}td[class=mobile-show] img{display: block !important;max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;}td[class=mobile-show]{display: block !important;max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto 
!important;}tr[class=gmail-fix]{max-height: none !important;display: table-row !important;background-color: #dae4e9 !important;}tr[class=gmail-fix] td img {max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;display: block !important;}tr[class=gmail-fix2] {max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;display: inline !important;}td[class="text-padding"]{padding-left:}div table {margin-left: 0 !important;margin-right: 0 !important;}td[class=show-pic-up]{display: block !important;max-height: none !important;}table[class=rc] img {width: 100% !important;max-width: 150px !important;height: auto !important;min-width:70px !important; padding-left:5% !important;padding-right:5% !important;display:block !important;}td[class=mobpr] {padding-left: 5% !important;padding-right: 5% !important;}}
</style>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td valign="top" width="100%"><table align="center" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="750"><tbody><tr><td class="mobile_hide" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="439"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b61332863-ef44-46d6-95cc-606115fe0c32%7d_fts_bp_header_a.png" style="display: block;" alt="THE BIGGER PICTURE FIFTH THIRD SECURITIES" border="0" height="95" width="750"></td></tr><tr><td class="header-logo" style="display: none; height: 0; width: 0;" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" height="0" valign="top" width="0">
<img class="mobile-logo1" src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{c57d1519-cbde-4575-8a3e-d946ba2b09d7}_mobile.jpg" style="display: none; height: 0; width: 0;" alt="THE BIGGER PICTURE FIFTH THIRD SECURITIES" border="0" height="0" width="0"></td></tr><tr class="gmail-fix2"><td bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="750"><table align="center" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="750"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="20">&nbsp;</td><td class="left-column" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="700"><table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="390"><tbody><tr><td class="padding3" style="padding-bottom: 16px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #005596; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="390">
<!--BEGIN ARTICLE TITLE-->
Financial conversations you should have with your spouse
<!--END ARTICLE TITLE-->
</td></tr>
<tr><td class="padding4" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 12px;" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="390">
<!--BEGIN ARTICLE CONTENT-->

Forty-three percent of people don’t know how much their spouse earns.<sup>1</sup> And that’s just one of the financial discussions that too many married couples keep to themselves — and that can set the stage for marital strife. To ensure you and your better half are on the same page about finances, use these tips to start the conversation. <br><br>
<strong>1. Assess Financial Habits
</strong><br>First, look at how each of you currently spends your money. How much are you spending on the essentials (bills) and extras (entertainment)? You should also review last year’s expenses to get a full picture of where your money is going. 
<br><br>
After looking at your current spending habits, discuss your short- and long-term financial goals, such as eliminating debt, saving for a home down payment or replacing a vehicle. 
<br><br>
Once you’ve established your objectives, define specific strategies for accomplishing your goals. Do you need to cut back on eating out? Or maybe you need to spend less on your yearly vacation. Whatever you decide, make sure your plan of action is realistic, and fits your and your spouse’s financial situation. 
<br><br>
<strong>2. Prepare for an Emergency 
</strong><br>As one of your goals, talk about creating an emergency fund. Sixty-four percent of people in America wouldn’t be able to come up with $1,000 in an emergency.<sup>2</sup> Don’t be part of this percentage. Plan how you’ll work together to prepare for the unexpected. 
<br><br>
Even if paying down debt is a primary goal, plan to set aside some money every month for your emergency fund. After all, if you can pull from this fund, you won’t need to add to your credit bills in the case of an emergency. It’s recommended to have three to six months of your monthly expenses saved.
<br><br>
<strong>3. Prepare for a Crisis
</strong><br>Review your life insurance needs. You will want more than your employer’s standard one year of salary benefit. Assuming both spouses are working, you should consider purchasing term insurance between 5 to 10 times your annual income, more if you are in your thirties with young children or have large debt obligations (mortgage). Term insurance is affordable and can be purchased for 10, 20 or 30 years. Your Fifth Third advisor can get you quotes from 30+ different insurance firms.
<br><br>
<strong>4. Update Your Wills 
</strong><br>Another essential discussion is how you want your assets distributed once you’re gone. In other words, it’s time to talk about your wills. Without this legal document, you could be leaving your spouse and/or children in a bind when you pass away. A will clearly establishes both of your financial wishes. 
<br><br>
It’s a good idea to review your will at least every five years and whenever an important life event happens — like becoming parents or buying a home. 
<br><br>
<strong>5. Revise Beneficiary Information 
</strong><br>Along with your will, make sure you’ve named beneficiaries for your retirement accounts. Keep these names updated on the same schedule that you review your will. Similarly, revise as needed based on life events. For example, if you named your mother as a beneficiary and she has since passed away, make sure to update the information.
<br><br>
<strong>A Prosperous Financial Future
</strong><br>Now that you have a basic framework for your financial conversation with your spouse, you should be on your way to a healthy and stress-free financial future together. But if you need some financial guidance and help with solutions to achieve your financial goals, Fifth Third Bank’s 
<a href="http://securitiesadvisors.53.com?elq=~~eloqua..type--emailfield..syntax--recipientid~~&elqCampaignId=~~eloqua..type--campaign..campaignid--0..fieldname--id~~&elqaid=~~eloqua..type--emailfield..syntax--elqassetId~~&elqat=~~eloqua..type--emailfield..syntax--elqassetType~~&elqTrackId=3a3a8be71e1e4bd6b8532d242c330647" target="_blank">investment professionals</a>
can assist you. <br><br>
<sup>1</sup> “One Thing You Should Know About Your Spouse, but 43% Don’t,” CNN Money, http://money.cnn.com/2015/06/24/pf/married-couples-salary/, accessed July 13, 2015<br><br>
<sup>2</sup> “Couples and Money: How much should we save in an emergency fund?,” by Catherine Alford, posted February 26, 2014, Go Girl Finance, http://gogirlfinance.com/money/couples-and-money-how-much-should-we-save-in-an-emergency-fund/, accessed July 13, 2015<br><br>
<sup>3</sup> “When should you redo your will?,” by Deborah L. Jacobs, posted August 9, 2012, Forbes, http://www.forbes.com/sites/deborahljacobs/2012/08/09/when-should-you-redo-your-will/, accessed July 13, 2015 <br><br>
Additional sources<br><br>
“5 Crucial Financial Conversations All Couples Must Have,” by Wendy Robinson, P&G Everyday, https://www.pgeveryday.com/health-wellbeing/love-relationships/article/5-crucial-financial-conversations-all-couples-must-have, accessed July 13, 2015<br><br>
“The Importance of Updating Your Beneficiary Information,” Late Career Newsletter, http://www.icmarc.org/news-and-views/late-career-newsletter/nl-retire-theimportance.html, accessed July 13, 2015
<!--END ARTICLE CONTENT-->

</td></tr>

<tr>
<td class="padding4" style="padding-top: 15px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 12px;" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="390">
<br><br>
Sincerely,<br>
<br>
<span elqid="23" elqtype="signaturelayout" class="remove-absolute" style="display: block"><p style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="FirstName">FirstName</span> <span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"></span><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="LastName">LastName</span> <br><span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="JobTitle">JobTitle</span></span> <span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"><br></span><eloquadependant type="sender" dependsonfield="Phone"><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="Phone">Phone</span>
</eloquadependant> <br><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="ReplyToAddress">ReplyToAddress</span><span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"> <br><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="PersonalURL" track="true">PersonalURL</span> <br></span></p></span>
<br><br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_First_Name1</span>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Last_Name1</span>
<br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Title1</span>
<br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Phone1</span>
<br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Email1</span>
<br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Purl1</span></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>

<!--BEGIN RIGHT COLUMN-->
<table class="rc" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280"><tbody><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280">

<!--BEGIN ARTICLE 2 PREVIEW-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="85"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="65"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="65"><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Avoid_taxing_moves?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=49c1fe22ab314d83a349b94923502c2a&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{b9c2367a-fd76-4c2a-ae3a-c71a7ec27286}_Avoid-Taxing-Moves-When-You-Retire.jpg" style="display: block; width: 65px !important;" alt="Avoid “Taxing” Moves When You Retire" border="0" height="70" width="65"></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
<td class="mobpr" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="185"><strong><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Avoid_taxing_moves?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=ba0d210f614247b88410b597aa701ad7&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #005596; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none">Avoid “Taxing” Moves When You Retire</a></strong><br><span style="color: #666666;">Relocating after retirement may be one of your dreams, but make sure you’re wide awake when you do your planning.<br><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Avoid_taxing_moves?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=20ce9e8df2fc4eb383103392b97dac7b&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#005596;">Read&nbsp;More»</a></span></td><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="10">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--END ARTICLE 2 PREVIEW-->

</td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b3e21864e-b5bf-4796-8b74-ed2988c83315%7d_bp_spacer_lt_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280">

<!--BEGIN ARTICLE 3 PREVIEW-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="85"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="65"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="65"><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Time_to_renovate?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=49c1fe22ab314d83a349b94923502c2a&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{88c43a07-f2fd-4233-8ead-90ef4eef1f7c}_Move-or-Renovate.jpg" style="display: block; width: 65px !important;" alt="Is it time to renovate — or move?" border="0" height="70" width="65"></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
<td class="mobpr" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="185"><strong><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Time_to_renovate?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=ba0d210f614247b88410b597aa701ad7&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #005596; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none">Is it time to renovate — or move?</a></strong><br><span style="color: #666666;">Weigh the pros and cons of remodeling versus buying a home before you make a decision.<br><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Time_to_renovate?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=20ce9e8df2fc4eb383103392b97dac7b&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#005596;">Read&nbsp;More»</a></span></td><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="10">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--END ARTICLE 3 PREVIEW-->

</td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b3e21864e-b5bf-4796-8b74-ed2988c83315%7d_bp_spacer_lt_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280">

<!--BEGIN ARTICLE 4 PREVIEW-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="85"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="65"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="65"><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Stay_tuned_life_ins?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=49c1fe22ab314d83a349b94923502c2a&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{1de0527f-9e71-4112-a661-1fbfc6373cba}_Life-Insurance-His-Final-Gift.jpg" style="display: block; width: 65px !important;" alt="Stay Tuned for Life Insurance Awareness Month" border="0" height="70" width="65"></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
<td class="mobpr" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="185"><strong><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Stay_tuned_life_ins?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=ba0d210f614247b88410b597aa701ad7&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #005596; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none">Stay Tuned for Life Insurance Awareness Month</a></strong><br><span style="color: #666666;">September is Life Insurance Awareness Month, so in our next issue, we’ll be featuring articles on this important topic.<br><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Stay_tuned_life_ins?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=20ce9e8df2fc4eb383103392b97dac7b&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#005596;">Read&nbsp;More»</a></span></td><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="10">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--END ARTICLE 4 PREVIEW-->

</td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b3e21864e-b5bf-4796-8b74-ed2988c83315%7d_bp_spacer_lt_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--END RIGHT COLUMN-->
</td><td bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="30">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="750"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b3e21864e-b5bf-4796-8b74-ed2988c83315%7d_bp_spacer_lt_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="20" width="10"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In future, please consider providing an [mcve], which will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sal B,
I would just throw some conditional Outlook tables around your two columns, and it will fix the issue. Please see below.

Here is an Email on Acid test showing this fix: https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/display/summary/6l3dz4a8ZQD2nuZ1Z7lePXDthCfScrxJPzu6tsxzesU82/shared

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Financial conversations you should have with your spouse</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 94%;">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<style type="text/css">
body, td, th {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #666666;}body {background-color: #FFFFFF;}a, a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {color:#005596;}@media only screen and (device-width : 720px) and (orientation : portrait),only screen and (min-device-width : 319px) and (max-device-width : 540px),only screen and (device-width : 800px),only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3) and (max-device-width: 718px),only screen and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){ table, table td {width: auto !important;}td[class=mobile_hide] {width: 0 !important;display: none !important;}td[class=mobile_hide] img {display: none !important;}td[class=header-img], td[class=header-img] img {width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;}td[class=img-right] {padding: 5% 7% 5% 5% !important;}td[class=img-right] img{width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;}td[class=left-column] {width: 
100% !important;}td[class=right1] {display: inline-block !important;width: 25% !important;height: auto !important;padding: 3% 2% 3% 3% !important;}td[class=right1] img{display: inline-block !important; width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;max-height: none !important;}td[class=right2] {display: inline-block !important;width: 60% !important;height: auto !important;padding: 3% 3% 3% 0 !important;font-size: 11px !important;max-height:none !important;}td[class=right2] img {display: inline-block !important;width: 60% !important;height: auto !important;padding: 3% 3% 3% 0 !important;max-height: none !important;}td[class=right3] {display: inline-block !important;width: 100% !important;height: 50% !important;}td[class=right3] img{display: inline-block !important;width: 100% !important;height: 65% !important;}td[class=padding3] {padding: 3% 3% 0 3% !important;}td[class=padding4] 
{padding: 3% 3% 3% 3% !important;}td[class=padding5] {padding: 0 3% 3% 3% !important;}td[class=space] {width: 100% !imporant;height: 3% !important;background-color: #ecf1f4 !important;}td[class=header-logo]{width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;display: block !important;}td[class=header-logo] img[class=mobile-logo1] {width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;display: block !important;}td[class=mobile_hide] img{display: none !important;}td[class=mobile_hide] td{display: none !important;}table[class=mobile-show]{display: block !important;max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;}td[class=mobile-show] img{display: block !important;max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;}td[class=mobile-show]{display: block !important;max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto 
!important;}tr[class=gmail-fix]{max-height: none !important;display: table-row !important;background-color: #dae4e9 !important;}tr[class=gmail-fix] td img {max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;display: block !important;}tr[class=gmail-fix2] {max-height: none !important;width: 100% !important;height: auto !important;display: inline !important;}td[class="text-padding"]{padding-left:}div table {margin-left: 0 !important;margin-right: 0 !important;}td[class=show-pic-up]{display: block !important;max-height: none !important;}table[class=rc] img {width: 100% !important;max-width: 150px !important;height: auto !important;min-width:70px !important; padding-left:5% !important;padding-right:5% !important;display:block !important;}td[class=mobpr] {padding-left: 5% !important;padding-right: 5% !important;}}
</style>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td valign="top" width="100%"><table align="center" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="750"><tbody><tr><td class="mobile_hide" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="439"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b61332863-ef44-46d6-95cc-606115fe0c32%7d_fts_bp_header_a.png" style="display: block;" alt="THE BIGGER PICTURE FIFTH THIRD SECURITIES" border="0" height="95" width="750"></td></tr><tr><td class="header-logo" style="display: none; height: 0; width: 0;" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" height="0" valign="top" width="0">
<img class="mobile-logo1" src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{c57d1519-cbde-4575-8a3e-d946ba2b09d7}_mobile.jpg" style="display: none; height: 0; width: 0;" alt="THE BIGGER PICTURE FIFTH THIRD SECURITIES" border="0" height="0" width="0"></td></tr><tr class="gmail-fix2"><td bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="750"><table align="center" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="750"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="20">&nbsp;</td><td class="left-column" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="700">
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
<table width="600" valign="top">
<tr>
<td>
<![endif]-->
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="390"><tbody><tr><td class="padding3" style="padding-bottom: 16px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #005596; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold;" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="390">
<!--BEGIN ARTICLE TITLE-->
Financial conversations you should have with your spouse
<!--END ARTICLE TITLE-->
</td></tr>
<tr><td class="padding4" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 12px;" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="390">
<!--BEGIN ARTICLE CONTENT-->

Forty-three percent of people don’t know how much their spouse earns.<sup>1</sup> And that’s just one of the financial discussions that too many married couples keep to themselves — and that can set the stage for marital strife. To ensure you and your better half are on the same page about finances, use these tips to start the conversation. <br><br>
<strong>1. Assess Financial Habits
</strong><br>First, look at how each of you currently spends your money. How much are you spending on the essentials (bills) and extras (entertainment)? You should also review last year’s expenses to get a full picture of where your money is going. 
<br><br>
After looking at your current spending habits, discuss your short- and long-term financial goals, such as eliminating debt, saving for a home down payment or replacing a vehicle. 
<br><br>
Once you’ve established your objectives, define specific strategies for accomplishing your goals. Do you need to cut back on eating out? Or maybe you need to spend less on your yearly vacation. Whatever you decide, make sure your plan of action is realistic, and fits your and your spouse’s financial situation. 
<br><br>
<strong>2. Prepare for an Emergency 
</strong><br>As one of your goals, talk about creating an emergency fund. Sixty-four percent of people in America wouldn’t be able to come up with $1,000 in an emergency.<sup>2</sup> Don’t be part of this percentage. Plan how you’ll work together to prepare for the unexpected. 
<br><br>
Even if paying down debt is a primary goal, plan to set aside some money every month for your emergency fund. After all, if you can pull from this fund, you won’t need to add to your credit bills in the case of an emergency. It’s recommended to have three to six months of your monthly expenses saved.
<br><br>
<strong>3. Prepare for a Crisis
</strong><br>Review your life insurance needs. You will want more than your employer’s standard one year of salary benefit. Assuming both spouses are working, you should consider purchasing term insurance between 5 to 10 times your annual income, more if you are in your thirties with young children or have large debt obligations (mortgage). Term insurance is affordable and can be purchased for 10, 20 or 30 years. Your Fifth Third advisor can get you quotes from 30+ different insurance firms.
<br><br>
<strong>4. Update Your Wills 
</strong><br>Another essential discussion is how you want your assets distributed once you’re gone. In other words, it’s time to talk about your wills. Without this legal document, you could be leaving your spouse and/or children in a bind when you pass away. A will clearly establishes both of your financial wishes. 
<br><br>
It’s a good idea to review your will at least every five years and whenever an important life event happens — like becoming parents or buying a home. 
<br><br>
<strong>5. Revise Beneficiary Information 
</strong><br>Along with your will, make sure you’ve named beneficiaries for your retirement accounts. Keep these names updated on the same schedule that you review your will. Similarly, revise as needed based on life events. For example, if you named your mother as a beneficiary and she has since passed away, make sure to update the information.
<br><br>
<strong>A Prosperous Financial Future
</strong><br>Now that you have a basic framework for your financial conversation with your spouse, you should be on your way to a healthy and stress-free financial future together. But if you need some financial guidance and help with solutions to achieve your financial goals, Fifth Third Bank’s 
<a href="http://securitiesadvisors.53.com?elq=~~eloqua..type--emailfield..syntax--recipientid~~&elqCampaignId=~~eloqua..type--campaign..campaignid--0..fieldname--id~~&elqaid=~~eloqua..type--emailfield..syntax--elqassetId~~&elqat=~~eloqua..type--emailfield..syntax--elqassetType~~&elqTrackId=3a3a8be71e1e4bd6b8532d242c330647" target="_blank">investment professionals</a>
can assist you. <br><br>
<sup>1</sup> “One Thing You Should Know About Your Spouse, but 43% Don’t,” CNN Money, http://money.cnn.com/2015/06/24/pf/married-couples-salary/, accessed July 13, 2015<br><br>
<sup>2</sup> “Couples and Money: How much should we save in an emergency fund?,” by Catherine Alford, posted February 26, 2014, Go Girl Finance, http://gogirlfinance.com/money/couples-and-money-how-much-should-we-save-in-an-emergency-fund/, accessed July 13, 2015<br><br>
<sup>3</sup> “When should you redo your will?,” by Deborah L. Jacobs, posted August 9, 2012, Forbes, http://www.forbes.com/sites/deborahljacobs/2012/08/09/when-should-you-redo-your-will/, accessed July 13, 2015 <br><br>
Additional sources<br><br>
“5 Crucial Financial Conversations All Couples Must Have,” by Wendy Robinson, P&G Everyday, https://www.pgeveryday.com/health-wellbeing/love-relationships/article/5-crucial-financial-conversations-all-couples-must-have, accessed July 13, 2015<br><br>
“The Importance of Updating Your Beneficiary Information,” Late Career Newsletter, http://www.icmarc.org/news-and-views/late-career-newsletter/nl-retire-theimportance.html, accessed July 13, 2015
<!--END ARTICLE CONTENT-->

</td></tr>

<tr>
<td class="padding4" style="padding-top: 15px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 12px;" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="390">
<br><br>
Sincerely,<br>
<br>
<span elqid="23" elqtype="signaturelayout" class="remove-absolute" style="display: block"><p style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="FirstName">FirstName</span> <span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"></span><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="LastName">LastName</span> <br><span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="JobTitle">JobTitle</span></span> <span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"><br></span><eloquadependant type="sender" dependsonfield="Phone"><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="Phone">Phone</span>
</eloquadependant> <br><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="ReplyToAddress">ReplyToAddress</span><span style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; COLOR: #666666; FONT-SIZE: 12px"> <br><span type="sender" elqtype="userfield" class="eloquasender" field="PersonalURL" track="true">PersonalURL</span> <br></span></p></span>
<br><br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_First_Name1</span>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Last_Name1</span>
<br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Title1</span>
<br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Phone1</span>
<br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Email1</span>
<br>
<span class="eloquaemail">FTS_Secondary_Purl1</span></td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<![endif]-->
<!--BEGIN RIGHT COLUMN-->
<table class="rc" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280"><tbody><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280">

<!--BEGIN ARTICLE 2 PREVIEW-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="85"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="65"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="65"><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Avoid_taxing_moves?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=49c1fe22ab314d83a349b94923502c2a&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{b9c2367a-fd76-4c2a-ae3a-c71a7ec27286}_Avoid-Taxing-Moves-When-You-Retire.jpg" style="display: block; width: 65px !important;" alt="Avoid “Taxing” Moves When You Retire" border="0" height="70" width="65"></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
<td class="mobpr" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="185"><strong><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Avoid_taxing_moves?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=ba0d210f614247b88410b597aa701ad7&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #005596; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none">Avoid “Taxing” Moves When You Retire</a></strong><br><span style="color: #666666;">Relocating after retirement may be one of your dreams, but make sure you’re wide awake when you do your planning.<br><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Avoid_taxing_moves?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=20ce9e8df2fc4eb383103392b97dac7b&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#005596;">Read&nbsp;More»</a></span></td><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="10">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--END ARTICLE 2 PREVIEW-->

</td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b3e21864e-b5bf-4796-8b74-ed2988c83315%7d_bp_spacer_lt_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280">

<!--BEGIN ARTICLE 3 PREVIEW-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="85"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="65"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="65"><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Time_to_renovate?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=49c1fe22ab314d83a349b94923502c2a&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{88c43a07-f2fd-4233-8ead-90ef4eef1f7c}_Move-or-Renovate.jpg" style="display: block; width: 65px !important;" alt="Is it time to renovate — or move?" border="0" height="70" width="65"></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
<td class="mobpr" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="185"><strong><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Time_to_renovate?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=ba0d210f614247b88410b597aa701ad7&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #005596; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none">Is it time to renovate — or move?</a></strong><br><span style="color: #666666;">Weigh the pros and cons of remodeling versus buying a home before you make a decision.<br><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Time_to_renovate?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=20ce9e8df2fc4eb383103392b97dac7b&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#005596;">Read&nbsp;More»</a></span></td><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="10">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--END ARTICLE 3 PREVIEW-->

</td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b3e21864e-b5bf-4796-8b74-ed2988c83315%7d_bp_spacer_lt_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280">

<!--BEGIN ARTICLE 4 PREVIEW-->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="280"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="85"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="65"><tbody><tr><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="65"><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Stay_tuned_life_ins?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=49c1fe22ab314d83a349b94923502c2a&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/EloquaImages/clients/FifthThirdBank/{1de0527f-9e71-4112-a661-1fbfc6373cba}_Life-Insurance-His-Final-Gift.jpg" style="display: block; width: 65px !important;" alt="Stay Tuned for Life Insurance Awareness Month" border="0" height="70" width="65"></a></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
<td class="mobpr" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="185"><strong><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Stay_tuned_life_ins?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=ba0d210f614247b88410b597aa701ad7&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #005596; font-size: 11px; text-decoration: none">Stay Tuned for Life Insurance Awareness Month</a></strong><br><span style="color: #666666;">September is Life Insurance Awareness Month, so in our next issue, we’ll be featuring articles on this important topic.<br><a href="http://investing.53.com/FTS_BP_AUG2015_Stay_tuned_life_ins?elqTrack=true&elqTrackId=20ce9e8df2fc4eb383103392b97dac7b&elqaid=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetId</span>&elqat=<span class=eloquaemail>elqassetType</span>" style="text-decoration:underline; color:#005596;">Read&nbsp;More»</a></span></td><td bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="10">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--END ARTICLE 4 PREVIEW-->

</td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#dae4e9" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7bb4d4ab28-0544-4031-9e16-1faac4bc30a1%7d_bp_spacer_med_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr><tr><td class="" bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="280"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b3e21864e-b5bf-4796-8b74-ed2988c83315%7d_bp_spacer_lt_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="12" width="280"></td></tr></tbody></table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
<!--END RIGHT COLUMN-->
</td><td bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="30">&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td bgcolor="#ecf1f4" valign="top" width="750"><img src="http://images.payments.53bank.com/eloquaimages/clients/fifththirdbank/%7b3e21864e-b5bf-4796-8b74-ed2988c83315%7d_bp_spacer_lt_blue.png" style="display: block;" border="0" height="20" width="10"></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr></tr></tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Geoff.